# Is there any way to include only the part of JS library which require in a page?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I want to load only those JavaScript code which is necessary in a page.

If suppose one of my page require just `.click` event then why do I include whole jQuery file?

Is there any way to include only the part of JS library which require in a page?

Comment: Most things can be done without jQuery, so you don't have to include it at all if you're worried about size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [build your own jQuery from source by using `grunt custom`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#custom-build-examples) and removing the [modules](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules) you don't want.

For example, to build jQuery without the `css` module (and all those that depend on it), you could build using:

```
grunt custom:-css
```

If we wanted to get even more minimal, we could remove more modules:

```
grunt custom:-ajax,-css,-deprecated,-dimensions,-effects,-event/alias,-offset,-wrap
```